# React invariant violation "Nothing was returned from render" - how to debug

Tags: reactjs

So, in my React app, every couple days or so, this occurs:

`Invariant Violation: Minified React error #152; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=152&args[]=t for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.`

It only happens in production, and BugSnag's logs don't yield any useful info either. Apologies for being super vague, but that's all the info I have. None of my render functions are missing a return statement, and no other errors seem to be involved.

Is there something I'm missing, or do these minified errors just make it completely impossible to debug? It doesn't even mention a component name or anything. Is there a means of debugging these that isn't just poking around in the dark?

Comment: You must have some developme t environment where you use non minified version of React, you can check there what is the error.

Comment: Hey Mohit, As I said above, this only happens in production - so it's essentially impossible to test in dev